# How To Submit Form If The User Don't Want To Add hasMany FormItems

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.7

I'm using `Laravel 5.7.*`.

I have `form` which hasMany `formItems`, Like a `form hasMany formItems` & `formItems belongsTo form`, but i want an `if` between them, that if user don't want to add `formItems` only `form` data store in `DB` and if user want to add `formItems` both data store in `DB`, right now, it's storing both data in `DB`, but i don't how to make it store if user don't want `formItems`.

**Here is my `FormController` `store method()`:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //SUBMITTING FORM DATA
    $form = Form::create([
        'user_phone' => $request['user_phone'],
        'user_name' => $request['user_name'],
    ]);

    //SUBMITTING FORMITEMS DATA
    $form_items = [];
    foreach($request['formItems'] as $form_item) {
        $form_items[] = new FormItem([
            'form_id' => $form->id,
            'family_name' => $form_item ['family_name'],
            'family_phone' => $form_item ['family_phone'],
        ]);
    }
    $form->formItems()->saveMany($form_items);
}
```

**Image For Better Understanding:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Feel free to leave the columns in the DB nullable too and just send back null values to those not added

Comment: i don't understand bro ....

Comment: when ever you create your tables in laravel let's say $table->string('address');  if you do $table->string('address')->nullable();  it allows that column to not have a value.  So what I would do is make that one model/table and make the columns nullable so if they don't submit them you don't error out.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a checkbox on your form to ask the user if they want to save form items too.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="save-form-items" value="true" id="save-form-items">
<label for="save-form-items"> Do you want to save form items?</label>
```

and then in your controller, you can do something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //SUBMITTING FORM DATA
    $form = Form::create([
        'user_phone' => $request['user_phone'],
        'user_name' => $request['user_name'],
    ]);

    if ($request->has('save-form-items')) {
        $form_items = [];
        foreach($request['formItems'] as $form_item) {
            $form_items[] = new FormItem([
                'form_id' => $form->id,
                'family_name' => $form_item ['family_name'],
                'family_phone' => $form_item ['family_phone'],
            ]);
        }

        $form->formItems()->saveMany($form_items);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   //SUBMITTING FORM DATA
   $form = Form::create([
       'user_phone' => $request['user_phone'],
       'user_name' => $request['user_name'],
    ]);


    $form_items = [];
    foreach($request['formItems'] as $form_item) {
      // when the user enter $form_item ['family_name'] && $form_item ['family_phone'] store the FormItem
      // or $form_item ['family_name'] || $form_item ['family_phone']
      // depending if both are required or not 
      if($form_item ['family_name'] && $form_item ['family_phone']){
        $form_items[] = new FormItem([
            'form_id' => $form->id,
            'family_name' => $form_item ['family_name'],
            'family_phone' => $form_item ['family_phone'],
        ]);
      }
    }

    $form->formItems()->saveMany($form_items);

}
```